# Elasticsearch function_score not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, search, filter

I'm using the following function score for outfits purchased:

```
{
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "purchased",
            "factor": 1.2,
            "modifier": "sqrt",
            "missing": 1
        }
    }
}
```

}

However, when I create a search - I get the following error:

```
"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [purchased] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
```

The syntax is correct for the search as I've run it locally and it works perfectly. I'm now running it on my server and it's not workings. Do I need to define purchased as an integer somewhere or is this due to something else?

Answer (score 0):

The `purchased` field is an analyzed string field, hence the error you see.

When indexing your documents, make sure that the numbers are not within double quotes, i.e.

```
Wrong:
{
    "purchased": "324"
}

Right:
{
    "purchased": 324
}
```

...or if you can't change the source documents (because you're not responsible for producing them), make sure that you create a mapping that defines the `purchased` field as being an integer field.

```
{
    "your_type": {
        "properties": {
            "purchased": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```